# magento newsletter status sent, recipients 0?

Tags: php, magento, newsletter

Ok so I have read everything under the sun about Magento cron jobs, and it appears as though it setup correctly. Here lies the problem:

I have the newsletter scheduled (qued) and it says sent under the status, but it says recipients 0? So nothing got send out? Why? I have almost 5000 subscribers?

Any ideas?

Meghan

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the cron.php file did not have the correct permissions set. After resetting the permission I am successfully processing the magento newsletter que as we speak.

I will keep you all posted in case it doesn't work, but for now it appears to be working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

The recipient 0 with sent status means you did not select a store from the Newsletter Queue form. Its not depending upon cron.php permission